# Why will my timer not detect it's over - tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, timer

I have tried modifying the initial if statement in checkTimer() which seems to be the problem, but none of the several solutions I tried over the past few hours have fixed this issue, they all had no effect, caused the timer to be inaccurate, or caused other problems.

The initial period of the timer has been modified to be one minute for testing.

```
# IMPORTS #

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.font import *
from playsound import playsound
import os
from itertools import cycle
import json
from tkinter import PhotoImage
import time
from ctypes import Structure, windll, c_uint, sizeof, byref

class LASTINPUTINFO(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('cbSize', c_uint),
        ('dwTime', c_uint),
    ]

def get_idle_duration():
    lastInputInfo = LASTINPUTINFO()
    lastInputInfo.cbSize = sizeof(lastInputInfo)
    windll.user32.GetLastInputInfo(byref(lastInputInfo))
    millis = windll.kernel32.GetTickCount() - lastInputInfo.dwTime
    return millis / 1000.0

t = time.localtime()
current_hrs = time.strftime("%H")
current_minutes = time.strftime("%M")
current_secs = time.strftime("%S")
current_hrs = int(current_hrs)
current_minutes = int(current_minutes)
current_secs = int(current_secs)
print(current_secs)
print(current_minutes)
print(current_hrs)


imagesCreated = 0
inARow = 0

# VARIABLES #

# minutes = cycle((25, 5, 25, 5, 25, 5, 25, 5, 25, 30))
minutes = cycle((1, 1))
notificationText = ""
directory = os.getcwd()
isTimerDone = False
onBreak = False
pomodoros = 0

jsonFile = open("Real-Time Drowsiness Detection OpenCV Python Source Code/VALUE.json", 'r+')
data = json.load(jsonFile)
drowsy = 0
workTime = 25

# FUNCTIONS #


# TKINTER #

window = tk.Tk()

window.title("Focus-Ware")
bigFontRegular = Font(
    family="Helvetica",
    size=35,
)
titleFont = Font(
    family="Helvetica",
    size=50
)
buttonimage = PhotoImage(file="Images/start.png")
bigFontItalic = Font(
    family="Helvetica",
    size=35,
    slant="italic"
)
regularFontItalic = Font(
    family="Helvetica",
    size=25,
    slant="italic"
)
window.geometry("510x600")
title = tk.Label(
    text="Focus-Ware",
    font=titleFont,
    foreground="black",
)
timerTitle = tk.Label(
    text="Timer:",
    font=bigFontItalic,
    foreground="black"
)
timer = tk.Label(
    text="Not Started",
    font=bigFontRegular,
    foreground="black"
)

reminderTitle = tk.Label(
    text=notificationText,
    font=regularFontItalic,
    foreground="black"
)

reminder = tk.Label(
    text="Last Notification:",
    font=bigFontItalic,
    foreground="black"
)


def doNothing():
    return "nothing"


pomodoroDone = False
target_hours = current_hrs
target_minutes = current_minutes
target_secs = current_secs
periods = 0

def setTimer():
    global target_minutes
    global target_hours
    global current_hrs
    global current_minutes
    global onBreak
    global periods
    global current_secs
    t = time.localtime()
    current_hrs = time.strftime("%H")
    current_minutes = time.strftime("%M")
    current_hrs = int(current_hrs)
    current_minutes = int(current_minutes)
    current_secs = int(current_secs)
    timer.config(text="In Progress")
    window.after(10000, checkTimer)

def checkTimer():
    global jsonFile
    global target_minutes
    global target_hours
    global current_hrs
    global current_minutes
    global onBreak
    global periods
    global drowsy
    global current_secs
    global target_secs
    jsonFile = open("Real-Time Drowsiness Detection OpenCV Python Source Code/VALUE.json", 'r+')
    drowsy = int(data["VALUE"])
    timer.config(text="In Progress")
    t = time.localtime()
    current_hrs = time.strftime("%H")
    current_minutes = time.strftime("%M")
    current_secs = time.strftime("%S")
    current_hrs = int(current_hrs)
    current_minutes = int(current_minutes)
    current_secs = int(current_secs)
    if get_idle_duration() >= 600:
        reminderTitle.config(text="Make sure to work!")
        playsound(f'{os.getcwd()}/Audio/GETTOWORK.wav')
    if drowsy == 1:
        playsound(f'{os.getcwd()}/Audio/wakeup.wav')
    if current_minutes == target_minutes and (target_secs == current_secs or target_secs < current_secs):
        onBreak = not onBreak
        timer.config(text="Completed")
        playsound(f'{os.getcwd()}/Audio/notification.mp3')
        if onBreak:
            if periods == 4:
                target_minutes = current_minutes + 30
                if target_minutes >= 60:
                    target_minutes -= 60
                    target_hours += 1
                periods = 0
            else:
                target_minutes = current_minutes + 5
                if target_minutes >= 60:
                    target_minutes -= 60
                    target_hours += 1

        else:
            target_minutes = current_minutes + 1
            target_secs = current_secs
            if target_minutes >= 60:
                target_minutes -= 60
                target_hours += 1
            periods += 1
    else:
        timer.config(text="In Progress")
    window.after(1000, checkTimer)




#
#
# def timerDone():
#     global onBreak
#     global isTimerDone
#     global workTime
#     global drowsy
#     drowsy = int(data["VALUE"])
#     if drowsy == 1:
#         workTime = 20
#     else:
#         workTime = 25
#     isTimerDone = True
#     reminderTitle.config(text="The timer is done!")
#     onBreak = not (onBreak)
#     if onBreak:
#         reminderTitle.config(text="Go on break!")
#     else:
#         reminderTitle.config(text="Get to work!")
#     window.after(2000, bruhwhatbruh)
#     if onBreak:
#         timer.config(text=f'Completed, take a break!')
#     else:
#         timer.config(text=f'Completed, get to work!')
#     playsound(f'{os.getcwd()}/Audio/notification.mp3')
#
#
# def bruhwhatbruh():
#     drowsy = int(data["VALUE"])
#     if drowsy == 1:
#         reminderTitle.config(text="You look tired!")
#
#
# def betweenTimers():
#     global inARow
#     global workTime
#     drowsy = int(data["VALUE"])
#     if drowsy == 1:
#         reminderTitle("You look tired!")
#         playsound(f'{os.getcwd()}/Audio/notification.mp3')
#         inARow += 1
#         workTime = 20
#     else:
#         workTime = 25
#     if inARow == 3:
#         inARow = 0
#         reminderTitle("Please take a break!")
#         playsound(f'{os.getcwd()}/Audio/notification.mp3')
#
#
# def setSubTimers(wkt):
#     for i in range(2):
#         if i == 0 or i == 1:
#             pass
#         else:
#             window.after((workTime * wkt) + round(2 / i) * 60 * 1000, betweenTimers)
#
#
# def setTimer(mins=25):
#     timer.config(text="In Progress")
#     setSubTimers(0)
#     window.after(2 * 60 * 1000, timerDone)
#     timer.config(text="In Progress")
#     window.after(workTime + 5 * 60 * 1000, timerDone)
#     timer.config(text="In Progress")
#     setSubTimers(1)
#     window.after(workTime + 5 + workTime * 60 * 1000, timerDone)
#     timer.config(text="In Progress")
#     window.after(workTime + 5 + workTime + 5 * 60 * 1000, timerDone)
#     timer.config(text="In Progress")
#     setSubTimers(2)
#     window.after(workTime + 5 + workTime + 5 + workTime * 60 * 1000, timerDone)
#     timer.config(text="In Progress")
#     window.after(workTime + 5 + workTime + 5 + workTime + 5 * 60 * 1000, timerDone)
#     timer.config(text="In Progress")
#     setSubTimers(3)
#     window.after(workTime + 5 + workTime + 5 + workTime + 5 + workTime * 60 * 1000, timerDone)
#     timer.config(text="In Progress")
#     window.after(workTime + 5 + workTime + 5 + workTime + 5 + workTime + 5 * 60 * 1000, timerDone)
#     timer.config(text="In Progress")
#     setSubTimers(4)
#     window.after(workTime + 5 + workTime + 5 + workTime + 5 + workTime + 5 + workTime * 60 * 1000, timerDone)
#     timer.config(text="In Progress")
#     window.after(workTime + 5 + workTime + 5 + workTime + 5 + workTime + 5 + workTime + 30 * 60 * 1000, timerDone)
#

def resetTimer():
    timer.config(text="Not Started")


def reminder_f():
    reminderTitle.config(text="Remember to pay attention!")
    playsound(f'{os.getcwd()}/Audio/notification.mp3')


Start = tk.Button(
    command=setTimer,
    text="Start Pomodoro",
    image=buttonimage
)
Start.config(height=100, width=100)
# DRIVER CODE #

# LOOP #
title.pack()
reminder.pack(pady=40)
reminderTitle.pack()
Start.pack()
timerTitle.pack(pady=40)
timer.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: *"the initial if statement in checkTimer() which seems to be the problem"* What is the problem? Did you check the return value of `get_idle_duration()` to verify the `if` condition?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to reinvent the wheel ... use python's datetime module to keep track of and compare times.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

target_time = datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=30)

def check_time():
    if datetime.now() < target_time:
        print("not yet ...")
    else:
        print("TIME'S UP!")
```

Comment: Still will not work. Did I do something wrong?

https://pastebin.com/D3brzdzP

Comment: Now it triggers early and does not stop triggering. https://pastebin.com/0SWL4K0V